# Adjust layout size to emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm starting to develop a launcher for in-car media display. I'm focusing it in 7 inch displays in landscape mode.

So, in the manifest I set:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Then in the layout Graphical mode i selected the 7" screen type, and I run a 7" tablet like emulator.

But when I start the app on the emulator, I get the layout oversized...

I tryed putting the main layout on the folder `layout-land`, and creating a folder called `layout-sw600dp`, but I'm getting the same result... What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way: Just have to have the main layout booth on the layout and layout-sw600-land folder. I was trying just to have it on the layout-sw600-land folder.